# Window Function: To include aggregated values into GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

2 questions on following:

1. 1st set of code yielded following response:

```
    WITH cte AS(
    SELECT
        cus.full_name AS full_name,
        SUM(rc.penalty) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) AS summary_penalty
    FROM customer cus JOIN rent_contract rc
        ON cus.id = rc.customer_id
    GROUP BY cus.full_name
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM cte
    WHERE summary_penalty >= 500;
```

> ERROR: column "rc.penalty" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Line: 4 Position in the line: 9 Make corrections and try again

May I know why is the aggregated column required to be included in GROUP BY clause in this case?

My quick fix is as follow:

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT DISTINCT
    cus.full_name AS full_name,
    SUM(rc.penalty) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) AS summary_penalty
FROM customer cus JOIN rent_contract rc
    ON cus.id = rc.customer_id
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE summary_penalty >= 500;
```

2. Which actually worked but from my learning I do not recall being taught to include DISTINCT to eliminate repeated rows. Is it safe to actually use **SELECT DISTINCT** when calculating with WINDOW FUNCTIONS in order to not use **GROUP BY**?

```
full_name   summary_penalty
Siro Aveni  510
Siro Aveni  510
Floriana Trevisani  1100
Floriana Trevisani  1100
```

Comment: You'd use aggregate SUM() function, not window one.

Answer (score 1):

`SUM(rc.penalty) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) AS summary_penalty` outputs on each row the sum that you would get by grouping by `customer_id`, but no aggregate is applied to this column when you then `GROUP BY cus.full_name`.

And you probably to `GROUP BY customer_id, cus.full_name` in case there are two different customers with the same name (*John Smith*).

If you want to show the total penalty for each customer whose total penalties come to over 500 then you need something like

```
SELECT c.id, c.full_name, SUM(rc.penalty) AS penaltySUM
FROM Customer c INNER JOIN rent_contract rc ON c.id = rc.customer_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.full_name
HAVING SUM(rc.penalty) > 500
```